# Any Typo in This Open Set & Closure Operation Problem?

Tags: general-topology

I am working on a problem from a class-note that is rife with typos, and I think there is also a bug here in this problem for I could not make any sense out of it:

If $\tau $ is a set of open sets in $X$ then the map $\chi : \mathscr P(X) \to \mathscr P(X)$ defined by  
$\chi (A) = \{ x \in X :$ for every $U \in \tau$ if $x \in U$ then $U \cap A $ then $\neq \emptyset \}$   
is an operation of closure.

Note that I copied it **exactly** as it is without any revision, with the definitions are for open set and operation of closure as follow:

Open Set: $\tau \subseteq \mathscr P (X)$ is a set of open sets in $X$ if $\tau$ satisfies the following:  
$(\mathscr O_1)$ : $\emptyset \in \mathscr \tau$  
$(\mathscr O_2)$ : $X \in \tau$  
$(\mathscr O_3)$ : If $\{ U_i \}_{i \in I} \in \tau$, then $\cup _{i \in I} \in \tau$  
$(\mathscr O_4)$ : If $U, V \in \tau$, then $U \cap V \in \tau$

Operation of Closure:  
$(\mathscr C_1) : \kappa (\emptyset ) = \emptyset $  
$(\mathscr C_2) : $ For $\forall A \in \mathscr P(X), A \subseteq \kappa (A)$  
$(\mathscr C_3) : $ For $\forall A \in \mathscr P(X), \kappa (\kappa (A)) = \kappa (A)$  
$(\mathscr C_4) : $ For $\forall A, B \in \mathscr P(X), \kappa (A \cup B) = \kappa (A) \cup \kappa (B)$.

My question is very simple: Do you see any typo here? Can you make any sense out of it? Thank you very much for your time and help. Happy holidays!

Comment: @BrianM.Scott : I am so sorry - I have just made the correction. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only direct problem I see is that
$$\chi (A) = \{ x \in X :\text{for every }U \in \tau\text{ if }x \in U\text{ then }U \cap A \text{ then}\neq \emptyset \}$$
should be
$$\chi (A) = \{ x \in X :\text{for every }U \in \tau,\text{ if }x \in U\text{ then }U \cap A \neq \emptyset \}$$
that is, without the second "then".

Also, the book really ought to use the standard term "topology" instead of "set of open sets", but that is probably on purpose ...

Comment: Thank you! I will tackle the problem again after getting convinced that there is no typo. Thanks again.